# Change the header and footer of PHPBB forum

Tags: coding-style, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm new to PHPBB forum, and I'm struggling to change the style of the header and footer. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing specifically what you are trying to do, you simply edit overall_header.html and overall_footer.html in /styles/themename/template/ for whatever you're trying to do.

If you want to pass variables to the template, you can do it in functions.php in the page_header and page_footer functions.